# bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 304: : No such file or directory when start zookeeper with JMX prometheus exporter

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to start zookeeper using kafka_2.12_2.2.0.

When I start normally it is working fine.

I want to export zookeeper metrics using prometheus JMX exporter.

I have `jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.11.0.jar` and  `zookeeper.yaml` in directory `/home/vagrant/prometheus`.

`/home/vagrant/prometheus/zookeeper.yaml` contents  -

```
    $ cat /home/vagrant/prometheus/zookeeper.yaml 
    rules:
    # replicated Zookeeper
    - pattern: "org.apache.ZooKeeperService<name0=ReplicatedServer_id(\\d+)><>(\\w+)"
        name: "zookeeper_$2"
    - pattern: "org.apache.ZooKeeperService<name0=ReplicatedServer_id(\\d+), name1=replica.(\\d+)><>(\\w+)"
        name: "zookeeper_$3"
        labels:
        replicaId: "$2"
    - pattern: "org.apache.ZooKeeperService<name0=ReplicatedServer_id(\\d+), name1=replica.(\\d+), name2=(\\w+)><>(\\w+)"
        name: "zookeeper_$4"
        labels:
        replicaId: "$2"
        memberType: "$3"
    - pattern: "org.apache.ZooKeeperService<name0=ReplicatedServer_id(\\d+), name1=replica.(\\d+), name2=(\\w+), name3=(\\w+)><>(\\w+)"
        name: "zookeeper_$4_$5"
        labels:
        replicaId: "$2"
        memberType: "$3"
    # standalone Zookeeper
    - pattern: "org.apache.ZooKeeperService<name0=StandaloneServer_port(\\d+)><>(\\w+)"
        name: "zookeeper_$2"
    - pattern: "org.apache.ZooKeeperService<name0=StandaloneServer_port(\\d+), name1=InMemoryDataTree><>(\\w+)"
        name: "zookeeper_$2"
```

`/etc/init.d/zookeeper` file contents are -

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #/etc/init.d/zookeeper
    DAEMON_PATH=/home/vagrant/kafka/bin
    DAEMON_NAME=zookeeper
    # Check that networking is up.
    #[ ${NETWORKING} = "no" ] && exit 0

    PATH=$PATH:$DAEMON_PATH
    export PROM_HOME=/home/vagrant/prometheus
    export EXTRA_ARGS="-javaagent:$PROM_HOME/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.11.0.jar=8080:$PROM_HOME/zookeeper.yaml"
    # See how we were called.
    case "$1" in
    start)
            # Start daemon.
            pid=`ps ax | grep -i 'org.apache.zookeeper' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
            if [ -n "$pid" ]
            then
                echo "Zookeeper is already running";
            else
            echo "Starting $DAEMON_NAME";
            echo "DAEMON_PATH is $DAEMON_PATH"
            $DAEMON_PATH/zookeeper-server-start.sh -daemon /home/vagrant/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
            fi
            ;;
    stop)
            echo "Shutting down $DAEMON_NAME";
            $DAEMON_PATH/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
            ;;
    restart)
            $0 stop
            sleep 2
            $0 start
            ;;
    status)
            pid=`ps ax | grep -i 'org.apache.zookeeper' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}'`
            if [ -n "$pid" ]
            then
            echo "Zookeeper is Running as PID: $pid"
            else
            echo "Zookeeper is not Running"
            fi
            ;;
    *)
            echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
            exit 1
    esac

    exit 0
```

when I uncomment the below 2 lines in `/etc/init.d/zookeeper` then it runs fine.

```
    export PROM_HOME=/home/vagrant/prometheus
    export EXTRA_ARGS="-javaagent:$PROM_HOME/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.11.0.jar=8080:$PROM_HOME/zookeeper.yaml"
```

Otherwise I get the below error -

```
    $ sudo service zookeeper start
    Starting zookeeper
    DAEMON_PATH is /home/vagrant/kafka/bin
    [vagrant@localhost ~]$ /home/vagrant/kafka/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 304: : No such file or directory
```

Below are my other detals -

```
    $ java -version
    java version "1.8.0_211"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.211-b12, mixed mode)
```

JAVA_HOME env variable is -

```
    $ echo $JAVA_HOME
    /usr/java/latest
```

OS details are -

```
    $ cat /etc/os-release 
    NAME="CentOS Linux"
    VERSION="7 (Core)"
    ID="centos"
    ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
    VERSION_ID="7"
    PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
    ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
    CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
    HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
    BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

    CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
    CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
    REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
    REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"
```

How can I resolve this issue and successfully export the JMX metrics for zookeeper?

Comment: `export EXTRA_ARGS` is missing a start quote

Comment: @cricket_007 - Its a typo mistake and I updated the post. I still get the same error.

Comment: Where did you get this init script? Are you aware Confluent Platform includes systemctl files for you? I don't have an answer here, but I suggest editing the kafka-run-class script to add a `set -x` to the top so that you can debug and see exactly where it failed

Comment: @cricket_007 - could you please let me know the directory of systemctl file kafka_2.12_2.2.0 version?

Comment: There isn't one included as part of what you've downloaded. It's part of Confluent Platform https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/rhel-centos.html

Comment: Also, I had a working repo that used Vagrant for installing all this (haven't tested recently) https://github.com/cricket007/cp-ansible-vagrant